# How do web search engines handle view pages?

Tags: views

When search engines are examining the content of a Drupal site how do they identify content assembled by a view?  A single view can have unlimited pages associated with it. In fact the entire content of a site can be provided that way.

Any resources on how these engines do their job in general (and for Drupal specifically) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SEO world, this is known as Duplicate Content, and it's something you want to avoid as much as possible. [[1]](http://blamcast.net/articles/drupal-seo)

This is dangerous territory for duplicate pages which can get you sandboxed by the search engines! [[2]](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect)

in drupal you can reach same page with lots of links: `node/123`, `node/123/`, `content/some title` and ...

one solution is [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module

Comment: Thanks, If I read the first link's recommendations, I should create a robot.txt file in the website's top directory that includes all URL aliases used by any views or panels etc. so that it is limited to nodes.

Comment: What about other entity types such as taxonomy or user?  Do you need to exclude those as well?

Comment: yes, you should remove duplicate links for taxonomy and user too